# Bibtex citations: cannot run aux file

Tags: biblatex, citing, texmaker, auxiliary-files

I have a problem to create citations in my text. I use Mac OS Sierra (10.12.6), TexMaker, and MacTex.

I created the .bib file with all references, but when I put `\cite{labelname}`, it cannot run (I also tried `\citep`, and other forms). I already configured the Quick build to run PdfLatex + Bibtex + PdfLatex(2x)+ View pdf, as described in another topic.

The error message says:

> Could not start the command.
>   "pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Another time the error message was, it could not find the .aux file.

The references appear now in the text as the names of the labels and I cannot change that into normal citations.

Comment: Please add a MWE showing your problem.

Comment: Usually you get `Could not start the command.` if your editor could not find the programme you are trying to run. Can you compile a small hello world document or do you get the same error?

Comment: In the .tex file it says "Undefined control sequence". In the .bib file it seems it does not find the file. The document can be compiled, but with the wrong format of citations. Sorry, I'm new to Latex, this is what you mean?

Comment: So where does the `Could not start the command` come into play? If you can start to compile a document, please show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) of what you have along with the output you get and the output you expect.

Comment: Having your main document open, press F11 on your keyboard. What happens?

Comment: Could not start the command is by .bib file Run. It says Process started and exited with error(s). I would expect to generate the citations in text. By Quick Build I get the pdf generated, with citations as label names, not in the correct form. Thanks!

Comment: You do not run any commands on the `.bib` file. Your editor and TeX are smart enough to figure out which commands to run on which file if you start them when the main document is in focus.

Comment: I see, thanks! I tried it, because the Quick build with the modified configuration did not work (PdfLatex + Bibtex + PdfLatex(2x)+ View pdf), and I wanted to try manually. Then what do you think, what causes the citations to be generated so weird, with label names in the text?

Comment: Please show us an [MWE (link!)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB (another link!)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) of what you are trying to compile. If you are really using `biblatex` I assume you run BibTeX instead of Biber, in which case you will want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. But that is pure speculation. **We can only help you if you show us an MWE and explain in detail what you are doing.**

Comment: I have text like this: Text \cite{label1}, \cite{label2},  \citep{label3}, \citet{label4},... and the result in pdf is only with label names. This is what you mean?

Comment: No, that is not what I mean. Please follow the three links in my last comment above and prepare a full working example of your document. Not just snippets.

Comment: Any news here? Can you show us a **complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)** ([I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864))? If you can't supply us with more information, I will vote to close your question as unclear what you are asking in due time.

Comment: Any news here? As I mentioned in my last comment, without an MWE your question can't really be answered.

Comment: I cannot produce an MWE, sorry. The document is very long, and I cannot copy the whole text here. The citations work with textcite, as I got an advise from a colleague later. Thanks for the comments.